# Clear pgbackups:transfer syntax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am attempting to use Heroku's newer pgbackups:transfer command to transfer data from production to staging databases. The documentation is difficult to understand, and S.O. answers seem to redirect people to use pgbackups:restore, which I know how to use.

**Documentation states**

```
$ heroku pgbackups:transfer HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK sushi-staging::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE -a sushi
```

When I run this as:

```
$ heroku pgbackups:transfer DATABASE_URL HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_IVORY sushi-staging::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_JADE -a warm-brushlands-XXXX
```

I get this error, along with several different possible syntaxes, all different from the first example:

```
!    Invalid argument: "sushi-staging::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_JADE"
  Usage: heroku pgbackups:transfer [SOURCE DATABASE] DESTINATION DATABASE

 direct database-to-database transfer

 If no DATABASE is specified, defaults to DATABASE_URL.
 The pgbackups add-on is required to use direct transfers

Example:

$ heroku pgbackups:transfer green teal --app example

note that both the FROM and TO database must be accessible to the pgbackups service
$ heroku pgbackups:transfer DATABASE postgres://user:password@host/dbname --app example
```

Variations on this theme produce the same error.

**I am looking for a clear syntax example** for pgbackups:transfer, something like:

```
$ heroku pgbackups:transfer -from source-app-name-XXXX -to destination-app-name-XXXX -confirm destination-app-name-XXXX
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clarification from the Heroku support team, my successful syntax looks like this:

**syntax**

```
heroku pgbackups:transfer source-color destination-app-name-XXXX::destination-color -a source-app-name-XXXX
```

**key**

source-color = each database on your app gets a color. if your database color is: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK, you will simply put 'pink' here, with no quote marks.

destination-color = the simple color of your destination database

source-app-name = the name of the source app, such as warm-brushlands-1111

destination-app-name = the name of the destination app

**Example**

Source app: young-refuge-1111.herokuapp.com
Source database: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK

Destination app: warm-springs-1111.herokuapp.com
Destination database: HEROKU POSTGRESQL_IVORY

```
heroku pgbackups:transfer pink warm-springs-1111::ivory -a young-refuge-1111
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change this

```
heroku pgbackups:transfer DATABASE_URL HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_IVORY sushi-staging::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_JADE -a warm-brushlands-XXXX
```

To this

```
heroku pgbackups:transfer HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_IVORY sushi-staging::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_JADE -a warm-brushlands-XXXX
```

i.e. remove the DATABASE_URL.  That should transfer HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_IVORY (assuming on prod) to HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_JADE (on staging).

Comment: Thanks for this, but it still throws the error "app not found". I was able to get some support from the Heroku team and posted my successful syntax below.